# Check category_name or taxonomy slug for a Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am checking the current page I am on and then using that to set a variable to change the category name like so.

```
    <?php
        if (is_page('apples')) {
            $categoryname = 'Apples';
        }

        $args = array ( 
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'products',
            'category_name' => $categoryname
        );

        $fruit_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $fruit_query->have_posts() ):
            while ( $fruit_query->have_posts() ) :
                $fruit_query->the_post(); 

                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                  the_post_thumbnail();
                }
            ?>

                <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong><br />
                Harvest Week: From <?php the_field('harvest_week_from'); ?> to <?php the_field('harvest_week_to'); ?><br />
                Colour: <?php the_field('colour'); ?><br />
                Market Season: <?php the_field('market_season'); ?><br />
                Market Sector: <?php the_field('market_sector'); ?><br />
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Link to product</a><br />

            <?php endwhile;
        else:
            // Insert any content or load a template for no posts found.
        endif;

        wp_reset_query();

    ?>
```

The problem however is that this a Custom Post Type so I think I should be checking the taxonomy since the category is not working. I have already tried examples from this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters but to no avail.

Is there something else I am mean to be doing? Thanks

**EDIT: This is the setup of my Custom Post Type**

```
    add_action('init', 'register_products');
    function register_products() {
    register_post_type('products', array(
        'label' => 'Products',
        'description' => '',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products', 'with_front' => true),
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes','post-formats'),
        'taxonomies' => array('category'),
        'labels' => array (
          'name' => 'Products',
          'singular_name' => 'Product',
          'menu_name' => 'Products',
          'add_new' => 'Add Product',
          'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product',
          'edit' => 'Edit',
          'edit_item' => 'Edit Product',
          'new_item' => 'New Product',
          'view' => 'View Product',
          'view_item' => 'View Product',
          'search_items' => 'Search Products',
          'not_found' => 'No Products Found',
          'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Products Found in Trash',
          'parent' => 'Parent Product',
        )
    ));}
```

**Screenshot of the Dashboard:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're actually using categories (and not a custom taxonomy) then your `$categoryname` variable needs to be the slug, not the actual name. Admittedly this Wp_Query argument name is confusing.

If, however, you are using a custom taxononomy (and you'll know if you are) then you should use

```
'name-of-your-custom-tax' => 'slug'
```

instead.

The codex is your friend:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: Thanks Vancoder I've tried numerous options and still it is not filtering as I would expect it. Admittdely I normally set these CPTs manually but this time I wanted to see how the Custom Post Type UI plugin would work for me so I used this to create the CPT. I have since moved the function into the functions.php (in the EDIT above) and added a screenshot of my dashboard for the products. I've used examples out of both those links you sent me and neither have done the trick.

Comment: Wondering - could it be that in this case, "Apples" is a child of "Product"?